# Consuming RSS in Django ( / Python)

Tags: python, django, rss

For a site I'm working on I would like to import a lot of RSS feeds using Django. Since I need the content of them fast I will need to cache them locally (either in the database or in some other way)

**Is there a standard app to do RSS consumption in Django, or is there a standard way to do this in Python?**

Of course I could implement it myself, but I'd rather reuse a good piece of code (since there's a lot of stuff to consider, like what to do when an item updates, how long to wait before checking for updates, etc, and I'd rather reuse someone elses thinking about this).

(I did google django and rss, but everything that seems to popup is feed generation; surely there must be other sites out there using Django and consuming RSS?)

Answer (score 8):

Check out<s>http://feedparser.org/docs/</s> http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/

One of the best Python libraries for parsing RSS and Atom Feeds; although it seems like you want to do a bit more (caching, auto-refresh etc.)

Comment: Caching can be done using django built-in fragment cache: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching